# run an external process from jsf / glassfish

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, netbeans, primefaces, glassfish

This is a jsf 2.0 project on GlassFish 3.1.2, developed with Netbeans.

In my business logic, I need to launch a perl application which returns a png or svg. This file will be displayed or presented as a file download in the UI (for which I will use primefaces).

**Question: How can an external process like this perl script be launched from my jsf app?**

(I have found a thread on this issue here: http://www.java.net/node/676943 but the answer was too technical, I could not understand it)

Thx!

Comment: take a look at this thread http://stackoverflow.com/q/2644297/617373

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("perl script.pl")` or you can use [Process](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) class.

Look at `exitValue()` and `getInputStream()`.

Comment: Ok that's simple I thought that the thing would be different in Java EE... actually not.