# How to run a batch file in jsp using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jsp

I want to execute batch file using javascript in jsp .I have created button in jsp file and on the click of that button i want to execute the batch file.Could some one help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644297/unable-to-start-bat-file-from-jsp

Comment: Batch file on the server, or on the client?

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18980957/is-it-possible-to-run-an-exe-or-bat-file-on-onclick-in-html